# Weka GUI: add attribute is-missing-value

Tags: weka, missing-data

I have a couple of attributes with missing values.

This is a survey, so the fact that the person refused to answer is, by itself, useful information!

I would like to create a new attribute called `is-missing-value = 1` if a given value in an attribute is a missing value and `0` otherwise.

Things I have tried:

- I have tried using **AddExpression**, but this seems to only perform arithmetic operations such as 2*attribute.
- I know that **MathExpression** allows using if-elses, such as `ifelse(A < 3.0, 1, 0)`... Do you guys know if/how I can test if a value is nan?
- **MakeIndicator** (or **NominalToBinary**) should be able to do what I want, but I think I need (i) to convert my missing values to a nominal value, so that then (ii) I can convert this new nominal value to binary. The problem is that **ReplaceMissingValue** only works for mode or mean; I need to be able to define a new value. One solution could be to Edit the data directly, but I'd rather avoid this.

Please notice that I need to do this using the Weka GUI, not the Java interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you:

1. copy the attribute (if you want the original one to remain): apply the `copy` filter (this and the following filters are all under `unsupervised/attribute` folder) with the index of the attribute
2. Convert your attribute to nominal using the `numericToNominal` filter (set the attribute index)
3. Fill the missing values with a new value using `ReplaceMissingWithUserConstant`. Here you need to specify the `nominalStringReplacementValue` parameter (e.g. "missing") in addition to the index of your attribute.
4. Apply the `NominalToBinary` filter on your attribute. This will create several new attributes (as the number of unique values in the dataset + the missing value). You can remove the attributes you don't need and keep only the missing attribute.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I ended up using Excel, but this is really clever, thank you!